# How to correct Excels format when downloading CSV data?

Tags: excel

Excel is currently downloading my CSV data into an improper format, is there a way to change the settings to download the exact numbers correctly? If I were to upload the data to google sheets from my download folder and then convert it to an excel file, it will download it without any issues. Currently using Excel for Mac Version 16.49. The data is downloading from Periscope.

[image: excel format]

[image: source format (correct format(]

Comment: You need to import the CSV and specify that field as text.

Comment: Also, please note that SO is for programming questions. This doesn't seem to be one. Probably better asked at Super User (where it's probably already answered in another thread, tbh).

Comment: Doesn't work because the data is download as a scientific number and seems to be hardcoded as that number displayed. Converting it to text only displays the downloaded value as text. It doesn't correct it to the appropriate long number.

Comment: ill find out there

Comment: thank you for pointing in the right direction!

Comment: "The data is downloaded as a scientific number" - please open the CSV in a text editor and see if that's the case. You need to *import* the CSV, not open it, and specify that field is text when importing.

Comment: Ill give it a try, thanks for sharing superuser as well. I didn't know it existed!